# Text is jumbled

Tags: text

On my Wordpress site, when I try to write an article, the text is randomly jumbling up. When I double click on it, the text straightens up but another set of text will jumble up. When I tried to copy it, it straightens up so I don't have a screenshot. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read [tour] and [ask].  Unless you are adding your own custom code to WP this probably belongs at sister site ServerFault.com but if you still think it belongs here instead you should edit your question to include more information about your setup including which plugins are enabled.

Comment: Thank you. I'll use ServerFault.